# How to use <execution> library in c++17

Tags: c++, c++17

Learning how to use the execution libraries in c++17. I am using Linux, but have also tried on my Mac. I get this error:

> fatal error: 'execution' file not found

when i compile in both OS's.

I would rather stick with linux where i type:

`g++ -g -std=c++17 ModuleDevelopmentStage13.cc -lboost_system -lboost_thread -pthread`

Perhaps I need to add some more libraries in the `-l....` arguments here. I am new to c++ and not sure where to find out which ones to add? I have installed the LLVM and tried a few options out there on similar posts but with no luck. Any advice?

so on my mac i did gcc -v and got:

`gcc -v Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0 Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`

Ok, so an update- I am now switched to gcc-9.1 installed via homebrew.

There are no "include" errors as before but I now have this issue when I try to compile simple code examples which use the c++17 libraries:

`g++-9 -std=c++17 example.cc 
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/pstl/parallel_backend.h:14,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/pstl/algorithm_impl.h:25,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/pstl/glue_execution_defs.h:52,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/execution:3,
                 from example.cc:6:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h:19:10 fatal error: tbb/blocked_range.h: No such file or directory
   19 | #include <tbb/blocked_range.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.`

I found the missing library and compiled like:

`g++-9 -std=c++17 example.cpp -I/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2019_U8/include/  -I/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2019_U8/lib/`

I got the following error:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_current_slot()", referenced from:
      tbb::interface7::task_arena::current_thread_index()      in ccnPixdL.o
  "tbb::interface7::internal::isolate_within_arena(t..........`

followed by many lines of similar.....feel like im closer but no idea how to move on this one?

Resolved with  `g++-9 -std=c++17 example.cpp -I/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2019_U8/include/  -L/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2019_U8/lib/ -ltbb`

Comment: Which version of GCC do you have?

Comment: And no, header files to be included with the `#include` preprocessor directive have nothing to do with linker libraries added with the `-l` (lower-case L) option.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57084789/edit) to include the information. There's a link also below the tags of your question.

Comment: done, I have now done an install of gcc-9.1 via homebrew and get another error (see question)

Comment: Ok, I've made some progress here but now have some horrible looking error (see main question)

Comment: Now it's time to learn about the options useful for libraries: The option `-I` (upper-case i) is to add a path to search for header files (`#include <...>`). The option `-L` is to add a path to look for libraries (the actual libraries, not its header files). And lastly the option `-l` (lower-case L) which is to add the library itself. Also note that you need to place the libraries (`-l`, lower-case L) last on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix it and it compiled and i ran the code, its a basic template but it doesnt throw error which is the main thing!

Answer (score 11):

You need to install tbb library.

On Ubuntu/Linux:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install libtbb-dev
```

On Mac with Homebrew:

```
$ brew install tbb
```

Then link runtime library in g++:

```
g++ -g -std=c++17 ModuleDevelopmentStage13.cc -lboost_system -lboost_thread -pthread -ltbb
```

Comment: Hi, I'm linking with both '-lpthreads' and '-ltbb' (is all of this using threaded building blocks under the hood?) but I still get "'execution' file not found"
I have this working on windows using visual studio but no luck on linux using clang (v9) - it stubbornly refuses to find <execution>!

Comment: Maybe you need to add the library path, something like this: -L/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2019_U8/lib/